# Uploading a file to an auto-upload input form with Selenium Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, file-upload

I am trying to see if I can upload a form through selenium driver on this page:

https://boards.greenhouse.io/6sense/jobs/240895

Here is my code:

```
file_element = browser.findElementByID("file") # just an abstraction, this part works
file_element.send_keys("/path/to/resume.pdf")
```

This is what the element looks like:

```
<form id="s3_upload_for_resume" data-key-template="applications/resumes/{timestamp}-{unique_id}-33183b0c37983a3799816701ed7d2135/${filename}" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://grnhse-prod-jben-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  ...
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

I thought that it could easily insert my file into the input box but instead I get a timeout and am asked to refresh the page. Does this have anything to do with how the file is uploaded to their servers? It's not a typical case of selecting the file and then pressing upload separately, so I feel like the auto-upload prevents me from putting my own file via Selenium. Is there another way around this?

Comment: I got `Application form expired. Please refresh the page and try again` even if I try to upload file manually

Comment: What browser are you using? It uploads normally on the latest Chrome for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually my file path. I had it as `/Users/folder\ with/space` and realized that I was writing the file path with bash syntax.. Python doesn't take that as valid input so it couldn't find my file. It worked once I removed the `\`.